# Checking amount of objects properties

Tags: javascript, oop

How to check in javascript how many direct properties object has? I want to know amount of direct properties in one object, not in prototypes chain. Is there any method to do so?

Comment: Yes there is a method to do so !!

Comment: Yes it's called [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). *Note:* I'm sure there is a duplicate for this question, I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek thank you very much! It's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an array of prperties and then take the length

```
var x = {
    x1 : 1,
    x2 : 2,
    x3 : 3,
    x4 : 4
};
console.log(Object.keys(x).length); // => 4
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on **which** properties you'd like to measure. Consider the following scenario:

```
const array = ["some", "values", "here"];
```

#### Object.keys

[**`Object.keys`**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.keys) returns an array of all *enumerable* properties that reside directly on the object (i.e. the prototype chain will not be checked).

```
Object.keys(array); // ["0", "1", "2"]
```

#### Object.getOwnPropertyNames

[**`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.getownpropertynames) returns an array of all *enumerable and non-enumerable* properties that reside directly on the object (i.e. the prototype chain will not be checked).

```
Object.keys(array); // ["0", "1", "2", "length"]
```

#### for…in loop

Using a [**`for…in`**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements) loop, you can iterate over all *enumerable* properties in an object *including* its prototype chain. In this scenario, this happens to be analogous to `Object.keys`, but this will not hold anymore once you're dealing with prototype chains.

```
for (const property in array) {
    console.log(property); // "0", "1", "2"
}
```

Determining how many properties an object has would then be as simple as either accessing `.length` on the resulting arrays or incrementing a property counter in the `for…in` loop.